# using multiple templates for listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have a listbox in my silverlight code :

```
  <ListBox x:Name="recepiesList"  ItemsSource="{Binding recepiesList}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewModelTemplate}" SelectionChanged="recepiesList_SelectionChanged" >

                    </ListBox>
```

the thing is that i have to have another type of listboxitem at the top of the list ( a sort of header ) . i've found multiple ways to have listbox's with multiple templates but they seem to complex for this sort of minor change.

Is there a way to include a  listboxitem to a listbox that has a applied template?

**UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION** I am asking this question because i am trying to take better advantage of the platform (being new to it); i don't know what the limitations of the templates in xaml are, i'm just looking for a better solution.

i am looking for a way to do something like this :

> listboxtype A
>
> listboxtype B
>
> listboxtype B
>
> listboxtype B
>
> listboxtype B
>
> listboxtype B

and due to the fact that i have some explicit information about listboxtype A (it's the first in the list and it only appears once), i was thinking that it could be added 'by hand' in XAML in some way.

Comment: So you already have multiple answers, but find them too complicated? And now you wait while they're all going to be proposed again, and decline them one by one?

Comment: You could use longlistpicker from the silverlight toolkit without the groups and with a header to the longlistpicker.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it's not that i am lazy, I just don't want to complicate my code unnecesary if there is a more elegant way to resolve my problem(and i haven't found one, hence the question-asking part).. i didn't mean to be disrespectful to the comunity.. i'm just new to the platform and am searching for ways to better take advantage of the features provided. If you consider that my question is not worth your time, please don't answer

Comment: Check out this: http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/09/28/datatemplateselector-in-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @abhinav suggested, i used a longlistpicker and was able to add a custom header template